# Plotting pixels to the screen using a physical Framebuffer (UEFI/GOP)

Tags: c, operating-system

I’ve been recently getting into OS development (completely from scratch), and I’m stuck on an issue where plotting pixels to the screen does not seem to work at all.

For reference, I’m using EDK2 for the UEFI utilities and compiling my bootloader using its build system.

I obtain the framebuffer from the GOP handle after setting my wanted mode (which should be 1366x768, BGRA colour format), but writing any value to the framebuffer memory space seems to not translate anything to the screen. Here are the projects (bootloader and OS) for references:

* OS: https://github.com/kernel-dev/kernelOS 
* Bootloader: https://github.com/kernel-dev/kernelOSBootloader

Furthermore, here are the relevant snippets of code that should work, but don’t:

* Function declarations: https://github.com/kernel-dev/kernelOS/blob/main/src/Kernel/Graphics/KernGraphics.c 
* Calling the function for clearing the screen: https://github.com/kernel-dev/kernelOS/blob/main/src/Kernel/Kernel.c

Comment: You might get more responses if you narrow down the problem yourself, and create something closer to a minimal example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  .  As it is, some kind soul needs to look over all of your tiny OS, possibly try building it, then debug it for you.

Comment: I sadly do not think it's possible to provide a minimal reproducible example, as it would indeed take some time to compile OvmfPkg (firmware for VMs), compile the bootloader and kernel itself into a PE32+ image, yes. Although I was hoping it’d be relevant to overview the method of obtaining the Framebuffer and validate that it is indeed sane. As well as the method of plotting pixels to the screen.

Comment: Launch QEMU with -s option. While QEMU is running your os, open a new terminal and type "gdb" then "target remote localhost:1234" in gdb. This makes you debug QEMU on port 1234 on localhost. Once debugging, you can type "dump memory FILE_PATH 0x1000 0x2000". Just replace 0x1000 and 0x2000 by the RAM range you are looking for. To examine the resulting binary file "hexdump -C FILE_PATH". This last command will give you the exact content of the file in its proper order. The data is thus little endian in the bash terminal. If you see 0x78563412 this corresponds to 0x12345678 (for a uint32 in C).

Comment: Also, in gdb type "info registers" to examine registers. You can set breakpoints in you code with infinite loops.

Comment: Alright, so, a binary dump from GDB has yielded that the entire memory region of my framebuffer (`0xC0000000`-`0xC0401000`) is just empty. There are no values there, at all. Everything is `0`. I'm not even sure how that is, when the screen itself has some white pixels. Also, I tried to write `0xFFFFFF00` to the _entirety_ of the framebuffer memory space, but that doesn't seem to do anything (when looking at the memory). I don't completely understand what I'm doing wrong. One of the only possibilities that I can think of is that the values packed inside of the LOADER_PARAMS struct are improper.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The reason why it wasn't working is because I wasn't properly getting the passed down arguments in my kernel.
This is how it looked like:

```c
// Entry point for kernel
VOID
KernMain (
    IN EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES                         *RT,
    IN EFI_KERN_MEMORY_MAP                          *MemoryMap,
    IN ACPI_DIFFERENTIATED_SYSTEM_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE  *Dsdt,
    IN KERN_FRAMEBUFFER                             *Framebuffer)
{
    ScreenClearTerminal (Framebuffer);
    //
    //  Should never reach here.
    //  Will be removed later.
    //
    while (TRUE) {};
}
```

However, the way I *actually* pass them down is like this:

```c
    //
    //  Prepare the arguments to be passed down.
    //
    LoaderBlock->MemoryMap          = &MemoryMap;
    LoaderBlock->Dsdt               = Dsdt;
    LoaderBlock->RT                 = SystemTable->RuntimeServices;
    LoaderBlock->Framebuffer        = FB;

    //
    //  Exit boot services.
    //
    /* ... */

    //
    //  Locate the EP function and call it with the arguments.
    //
    typedef void (__attribute__((ms_abi)) *EntryPointFunction) (LOADER_PARAMS *LP);
    EntryPointFunction EntryPointPlaceholder = (EntryPointFunction) (BaseAddress + EntryPoint);
    EntryPointPlaceholder (LoaderBlock);
```

It's contained inside of a struct. So the appropriate way to *obtain* them would be like this:

```c
/**
    A structure used to "contain" all
    the parameters to be passed down
    to the kernel's EP. 
 **/
typedef struct {
    EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES                         *RT;           /// Pointer to the runtime services.
    EFI_KERN_MEMORY_MAP                          *MemoryMap;    /// Pointer to the EFI_KERN_MEMORY_MAP.
    ACPI_DIFFERENTIATED_SYSTEM_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE  **Dsdt;        /// Pointer to the DSDT pointer.
    KERN_FRAMEBUFFER                             *Framebuffer;  /// Pointer to the KERN_FRAMEBUFFER.
} LOADER_PARAMS;

// Entry point for kernel
VOID
KernMain (
    LOADER_PARAMS *LP)
{
    ScreenClearTerminal (LP->Framebuffer);

    //
    //  Should never reach here.
    //  Will be removed later.
    //
    while (TRUE) {};
}
```

or, alternatively keeping the old method, but alternating the way they're passed down:

```c
    //
    //  Locate the EP function and call it with the arguments.
    //
    typedef void (__attribute__((ms_abi)) *EntryPointFunction) (
        EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES                         *RT,
        EFI_KERN_MEMORY_MAP                          *MemoryMap,
        ACPI_DIFFERENTIATED_SYSTEM_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE  **Dsdt,
        KERN_FRAMEBUFFER                             *Framebuffer
    );

    EntryPointFunction EntryPointPlaceholder = (EntryPointFunction) (BaseAddress + EntryPoint);
    EntryPointPlaceholder (
        SystemTable->RuntimeServices,
        &MemoryMap,
        Dsdt,
        FB);
```

Completely my bad lol.

Thank you to @user123 and @Dave S for helping me.